# Pycharm doesnt reslove package dependencies

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I installed a pycharm application and did configure interpreter. After i installed spark-nlp package via pip inside pycharm, and tried to run programm, it showed that it missing dependecy in form of pyspark package. When I installed pyspark it complained about bunch of packages that are being missing. Shouldn't venv resolve all requirements automatically?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work "pip" should be associated with the Python interpreter you have specified in Pycharm.

Can you check if the interpreter specified in Pycharm and "pip" on the terminal are pointing to same virtualenv which was created?

I believe "pip" on pycharm-terminal is different and not pointing to virtualenv used by Pyharm.